# Tri-nested loop in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, seurat

Currently, I am writing a function that uses a tri nested loop in R; however, it appears to have some strange behavior. I am noticing the following issues:

1) gene does not appear to be appended gene to gene.out at the end of the loop, the list I get from gene.out is gene.use.

2) cond ONLY makes duplicates (i.e 22_22, 35_35, ect)

As far as I can tell neither of these things should be happening in the third loop. Is this some weird R loop behavior or is this a coding mistake?

Here is the code in question:

```
for (gene in genes.use){

    for (i in groups){
      cat(paste("i: ",i, "\n"))

      i_cells = rownames(SerautObj@meta.data[SerautObj@meta.data[[group.by]] == i,])
      i_vector = SerautObj@assays[[assay]]@data[gene, i_cells]

      for(j in groups){
        cat(paste("j: ",j, "\n"))

        j_cells = rownames(SerautObj@meta.data[SerautObj@meta.data[[group.by]] == j,])
        j_vector = SerautObj@assays[[assay]]@data[gene, j_cells]


        cond = paste(i, j, sep = "_")
        cat(paste(gene, cond, sep = "\n"))

        #preform t-test
        t_out = t.test(i_vector, j_vector)

        #constuct outs

        condition.out <- c(condition.out, cond)



        stat.out <- c(stat.out, t_out[["statistic"]])
        p_val.out <- c(p_val.out, t_out[["p.value"]])
        gene.out <- c(gene.out, gene)
        }
    }
}
```

edit:

Forgot to include, When I do print(paste("i: ", i) in the i loop and print(paste("j: ", j)) I get:

i:  group1
 i:  group2
 i:  group3
 j:  group1
 j:  group2
 j:  group3

Toy set data from https://satijalab.org/seurat/v3.1/pbmc3k_tutorial.html:

```
SerautObj@meta.data
structure(list(orig.ident = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "pbmc3k", class = "factor"), nCount_RNA = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), nFeature_RNA = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), group = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5)), row.names = c("AAACATACAACCAC", "AAACATTGAGCTAC", "AAACATTGATCAGC", 
"AAACCGTGCTTCCG", "AAACCGTGTATGCG", "AAACGCACTGGTAC", "AAACGCTGACCAGT", 
"AAACGCTGGTTCTT", "AAACGCTGTAGCCA", "AAACGCTGTTTCTG"), class = "data.frame")

SerautObj@assays[[assay]]@data

    new("dgCMatrix", i = integer(0), p = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Dim = c(10L, 10L), Dimnames = list(c("AL627309.1", 
"AP006222.2", "RP11-206L10.2", "RP11-206L10.9", "LINC00115", 
"NOC2L", "KLHL17", "PLEKHN1", "RP11-54O7.17", "HES4"), c("AAACATACAACCAC", 
"AAACATTGAGCTAC", "AAACATTGATCAGC", "AAACCGTGCTTCCG", "AAACCGTGTATGCG", 
"AAACGCACTGGTAC", "AAACGCTGACCAGT", "AAACGCTGGTTCTT", "AAACGCTGTAGCCA", 
"AAACGCTGTTTCTG")), x = numeric(0), factors = list())

genes.use = c("PLEKHN1", "HES4", "NOC2L")
groups = Map(c, unique(SerautObj@meta.data$groups))
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Could you make your example reproducible by giving us a minimal data frame to work with? After stripping your data frame down to just a few records, you can copy the output of `dput(dataframe_name)` into your code block and we'll be able to recreate it.

Comment: Iterating over `i, j` can typically be simplified to a vectorized set of operations

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with r yet to know what commands I should use for that, I am much more comfortable with loops. Do you have any recommendations on where to look?

Comment: @Connorr.0 - if you're interested, check out the apply family of functions in R (apply, sapply, lapply, mapply). And also functional programming as a general topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the issue was with:

```
Map(c, unique(SerautObj@meta.data$groups))
```

I then tried:

```
as.list(unique(SerautObj[["time"]]))
```

This had the same problem, but this was fixed with:

```
unlist(as.list(unique(SerautObj[["time"]])))
```

It appears that there is weird for loop behavior over lists and you need to go to an atomic type vector or you can end up with duplicates. I'm guessing there is some strange referencing happening or something with loops over lists.

Comment: If this worked, please accept as a solution - tick.